# Send long text message on android via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using the example app from android : BluetoothChat.
But when I try to sent string that it size greater the 1024 byte the message don't transfer.
I try to change the code below to send more then 1024 byte but I don't success in this.
Please help me.

Read code:

```
public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(SmallWorld.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                            buffer).sendToTarget();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

send code:

```
public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler
                    .obtainMessage(SmallWorld.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
```

call to write:

```
    String message="blabla";
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);
```

Comment: what's the error message you get?

Comment: I don't get error message, it send just 1024 byte string (it cut the string), Even if I change the size of the buffer.

Comment: where is the code to send the string

Comment: how are you calling write? Make sure that the buffer being passed to write is not limited to 1024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the write you may want to flush the stream to force the data to be sent out, because it could be that the stream is buffering the data and waiting for more before actuatlly sending out the data.
Try ..

```
mmOutStream.write(buffer);
mmOutStream.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: It worked, but now I have a new problem. What is the maximum size of the array :new byte[1024];
I get a memory leak